# Unable to transition a D3v4 Stacked Bar Chart on data refresh

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I currently have a stacked bar chart created in D3V4 based on this example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/b5935342c6d21928111928401e2c8608)

The chart is an Ember component and works well but I am unable to add a transition affect when the data changes. Currently, when the data changes the graph redraws correctly but I have been unable to get a smooth transition between the two states.

When adding a transition() item anywhere in the chart construction it either stops rendering completely or stops redrawing the chart.

The charts is produced by three functions inside my componentjs:

didInsertElement:

```
   didInsertElement() {
        this.buildChart()
        this.set('didRenderChart', true);
      },
```

didUpdateAttrs:

```
  didUpdateAttrs() {
    let svg = select(this.$('svg')[0])
        .selectAll("g")
        .remove()
    this.buildChart()
  },
```

and buildChart (only construction code reproduced, tooltips and legends parsed out)

```
buildChart() {
    let data = this.get('data')

let series = stack()
      .keys(["count1", "count2", "count3"])
      .offset(stackOffsetDiverging)
      (data);

   let svg = select(this.$('svg')[0]),
      margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 60
      },
      width = this.get("width"),
      height = this.get("height");

    let x = scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.label;
      }))
      .rangeRound([margin.left, width - margin.right])
      .padding(0.1);

    let y = scaleLinear()
      .domain([min(series, stackMin), max(series, stackMax)])
      .rangeRound([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

    let z = scaleOrdinal().range(COLORS[this.get('color')]);

    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(series)
      .enter()
      // .merge(svg)
      .append("g")
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return z(d.key);
      })
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth)
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.data.label);
      })

      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d[1]);
      })

      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]);
      })

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
      .attr("class", "axisWhite")
      .call(axisBottom(x))

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
      .attr("class", "axisWhite")
      .call(axisLeft(y))


    function stackMin(h) {
      return min(h, function(d) {
        return d[0];
      });
    }

    function stackMax(h) {
      return max(h, function(d) {
        return d[1];
      });
    }
```

I assume the inability to transition is because the chart is not being created correctly in the first place (something to do with everything being appended to 'g') but I have been unable to work out what changes I need to make to correct this.

Note that the D3v4 functions are being imported into the component from an ember add on so do not need the d3.namespace. Unfortunately I have been unable to recreate it in JSFiddle or Ember Twiddle

Comment: It looks like right now you are just removing the chart and replotting it. Could you post some code of what you have tried for the transition so we can help better!

Comment: Hi pmkro - you are correct, that is pretty much exactly what I am doing! My efforts in attempting the transition so far have literally just been adding .transition() at various points in build chart as that is all I needed to do for a seperate, non stacked bar chart. I suspect the other vertical chart was constructed a lot better though! I am very new to D3 and I think I need to redraw the chart in a different way  when the data changes but I am completely stuck!

Comment: Here is a link to the [general update pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218). Should point you in a good direction.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at this before and supposed that the transition needs to be applied after the `.enter()` after `.selectAll('rect')`. This produces a strange transition of all the rectangles being drawn at once from the top left and stops both axis from rendering as well as making the chart non responsive to data refreshes. Trying to add the transition() after the g elements have been selected and entered stops the chart from rendering at all!